# Getting Nan Error in react native timer app

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

I have recently started working on react native, and I am currently working on the below code for timer and countdown functionality. Before I am able to put specific time and it is working fine. Also I am able to increment and decrement static values, but on timer getting error.

In the below code while incrementing and decrementing the time, I am getting 'NaN' as output.

```
//Timing.js

export const Timing = ({ onChangeTime }) => {
    

  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.timingButton}>
        <RoundedButton size={75} title="+" onPress={() => onChangeTime(onChangeTime + 1)} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.timingButton}>
        <RoundedButton size={75} title="15" onPress={() => onChangeTime(15)} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.timingButton}>
        <RoundedButton size={75} title="-" onPress={() => onChangeTime(onChangeTime -1)} />
      </View>
    </>
  );
};


//Timer.js
export const Timer = ({ focusSubject, clearSubject, onTimerEnd }) => {
  useKeepAwake();
  const [isStarted, setIsStarted] = useState(false);
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(1);
  const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(0.1);

  const onEnd = (reset) => {
    Vibration.vibrate(PATTERN);
    setIsStarted(false);
    setProgress(1);
    reset();
    onTimerEnd(focusSubject);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.countdown}>
        <Countdown
          minutes={minutes}
          isPaused={!isStarted}
          onProgress={setProgress}
          onEnd={onEnd}
        />
        <View style={{ paddingTop: spacing.xxl }}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Focusing on:</Text>
          <Text style={styles.task}>{focusSubject}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={{ paddingTop: spacing.sm }}>
        <ProgressBar
          progress={progress}
          color={colors.progressBar}
          style={{ height: spacing.sm }}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.timingWrapper}>
        <Timing onChangeTime = {setMinutes} />
      </View>

      <View style={styles.buttonWrapper}>
        {!isStarted ? (
          <RoundedButton title="start" onPress={() => setIsStarted(true)} />
        ) : (
          <RoundedButton title="pause" onPress={() => setIsStarted(false)} />
        )}
      </View>
      <View style={styles.clearSubjectWrapper}>
        <RoundedButton size={50} title="-" onPress={clearSubject} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

//Countdown.js
const minutesToMillis = (min) => min * 1000 * 60;
const formatTime = (time) => (time < 10 ? `0${time}` : time);
export const Countdown = ({ minutes = 0.1, isPaused, onProgress, onEnd }) => {
  const interval = React.useRef(null);

  const [millis, setMillis] = useState(null);

  const reset = () => setMillis(minutesToMillis(minutes))
  
  const countDown = () => {
    setMillis((time) => {
      if (time === 0) {
        clearInterval(interval.current);
        onEnd(reset);
        return time;
      }
      const timeLeft = time - 1000;
      return timeLeft;
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setMillis(minutesToMillis(minutes));
  }, [minutes]);

  useEffect(() => {
    onProgress(millis / minutesToMillis(minutes));
  }, [millis]);

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   onIncrement(millis / minutesToMillis(minutes)+1000);
  // },[millis]);


  useEffect(() => {
    if (isPaused) {
      if (interval.current) clearInterval(interval.current);
      return;
    }

    interval.current = setInterval(countDown, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval.current);
  }, [isPaused]);

  const minute = Math.floor(millis / 1000 / 60) % (60);
  const seconds = Math.floor(millis / 1000) % (60);
  return (
    <Text style={styles.text}>
      {formatTime(minute)}:{formatTime(seconds)}
    </Text>
  );
};
```

Comment: I am not well versed with React so i am not sure but, are you sure ```onChangeTime(onChangeTime -1)``` this is correct way to decrement? can you debug to check it or ```console.log``` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `Timing` likewise

```
export const Timing = ({ onChangeTime }) => {
    

  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.timingButton}>
        <RoundedButton size={75} title="+" onPress={() => onChangeTime(prev => prev + 1)} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.timingButton}>
        <RoundedButton size={75} title="15" onPress={() => onChangeTime(15)} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.timingButton}>
        <RoundedButton size={75} title="-" onPress={() => onChangeTime( prev => prev - 1)} />
      </View>
    </>
  );
};
```